# how to add data in existing array file.i need to read data from text file then ask user whether user want to add data and save it in the same file

Tags: c++, append, ofstream

first,i read the text file

```
ifstream inFile;  /*open file*/
inFile.open("data.txt");  

while(!inFile.eof())  
{  
    if(inFile.eof()==true)  
    break;  

    else  
    {  
        inFile>>n[count]>>i[count]>>g[count]>>s[count];  
        count++;  
    }  
}
```

then i need to ask user whether he want to add more data.

if yes, i user enter the  data which  is name,ic,gender and state.

then,store it in the same file.

please help me.

Comment: 1) ask the question, 2) input the data, 3) add the new data to your arrays, 4) open the file for output 5) write the arrays to the output file in a loop. There I've split the task into five sub tasks. Now have a go at the sub tasks **one at a time**. That last part is really important. The way to make progress in programming is to split complex tasks into manageable parts. If you get stuck on any of the sub tasks, then come back here, ask another question and post the code you written to try and solve the problem

Comment: I dont get it... i can do no.1 and 2 but no.3 i dont know what to use or do.

Comment: In the code above you have four arrays `n`, `i`, `g` and `s` and a `count` variable that tell you how many items are in the arrays. The loop adds items to the array when they are read from a file. Adding items to the arrays when they have been entered by the user is exactly the same. `n[count] = something; i[count] = something_else; ...; count++;` If that's not clear then you need to show the code you have written so far (in a new question).